# How to put comma to all money fields (decimal attributes) in a model in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm working on a Project where I have a lot of decimal fields in every model and want to put comma all of them.
I can use helper mutators or PHP `number_format()` while fetching. The problem is I have to do it for every field.

Is there any simple solution for this??

Want to put Comma Form
Create Form Sample:
[image: Create Form Sample]

Index Page/Show Page Sample:
[image: Index Page/Show Page Sample]

Comment: try this `number_format("1000000",2,",",",");` here `number_format(number,decimals,decimalpoint,separator);`

Comment: I think it's a better idea to do this in the front-end side rather than on the database side with a bit of JavaScript or in the blade code that generates that page. Mutators are not even appropriate for this sort of problem because they create a mess when trying to manipulate values in code as well since you're converting numbers to strings that can't easily be converted back

Comment: JS is potentially a better idea (as mentioned above), however, you could use a [Custom cast](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#custom-casts) for something like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use custom casts :

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#castables

So for example

create a ReadableNumber class :

```
<?php

namespace App\Casts;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Database\Eloquent\CastsAttributes;

class ReadableNumber implements CastsAttributes
{
  
    /**
     * Prepare the given value for storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  array  $value
     * @param  array  $attributes
     * @return string
     */
    public function get($model, $key, $value, $attributes)
    {
        return number_format($value, 2, ',', ' '); 
    }

    public function set($model, $key, $value, $attributes)
    {
        return str_replace(" ", "", str_replace(",", ".", $value));
    }
}
```

```
protected $casts = [
    'size' => ReadableNumber::class,
    'rate' => ReadableNumber::class,
    'value' => ReadableNumber::class,
    [...]
];
```

then in your blade vues :

```
{{ $appart->value }}
```

will show : `3 000,00`

Comment: Nice and clean! Make sure to use CastsAttributes instead of CastsInboundAttributes or the getter will not be called.